# HTML: How to make an image NOT have influence on the width of whole site?

Tags: html, css, image, width, border

I have 2 images left and right from center which are placed nicely, but when the screensize is < 1920px, a scrollbar is created because the right image is going "out of the Site". I just want it to be cut to the screensize / go over the side of the screen without widening it.

CSS of the images (simply placed in the body):

```
#fans_l {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: -955px;
 margin-top: -228px;
 z-index:3;
}

#fans_r {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 399px;
 margin-top: -228px;
 z-index:3;
}
```

Body css:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-image:url(p/back.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat; text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: please add a cde sample with html, preferably include a live working example such as jsfiddle / codepen / plunkr

Comment: `overflow-x:hidden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, there are a few things you can do. The first two that come to mind are as follows:

1. You can declare in the body css that the overflow-x property be set to either none or hidden, effectively cutting off your excess pixels. Though, at a fixed image size, this may not be desirable on smaller browsers. Keep in mind that many people have monitors smaller than 1920px.
2. You can use a nifty little tool present in CSS3 called Media Queries. With them, you can change css rules based on a monitor width or height. Using this method, you can ensure that it appear full on all sizes of browser windows.

Comment: Glad to be of some help to you!